# Error al crear una función en postgreSQL con integración Python en Windows 10: La aplicación ha perdido la conexión con la base de datos

Tags: python, postgresql, windows10, pgadmin

Tratando de integrar Python a PGAdmin de PostgreSQL me encontré con este problema, no me deja crear una función.

Para ir paso por paso primero cree la extensión Python:

```
CREATE EXTENSION plpython3u;
```

el cual resulto exitoso: bueno, al comienzo no, ya que tuve algunos errores, pero los solucioné.
Agregué Python al entorno de variables, así también agregué *python39.dll* a system32 el cual era un requerimiento y así al fin pude crear la extensión Python.

Aquí viene mi infierno: desde hace un día entero que no logro solucionarlo y es que al tratar de crear una simple función no me deja, ya que me sale una Advertencia de Conexión y con ello el siguiente aviso…

> La aplicación ha perdido la conexión con la base de datos:
>
> > - Si la conexión estuvo inactiva pudo haber sido desconectada a la fuerza.
> > - El servidor de la aplicación o el servidor de la base de datos pueden haber sido reiniciados.
> > - La sesión de usuario pudo superar el límite de tiempo. Do you want to continue and establish a new session

Este mismo aviso me aparece al tratar de crear la extensión Python, pero cuando le doy a *Continuar* lo crea sin problemas, sin embargo, al tratar de crear la función y le doy a *Continuar* me vuelve a salir el mismo aviso una y otra vez sin parar hasta que yo le dé a *Cancelar*.

Les dejo unas imágenes para que vean que sí tengo Python agregado a las variables y también una muestra del error que lanza en el log.

[image: ahi como verán]

Comment: ¿El servicio de **Postgresql** está en ejecución?

Comment: El aviso te está indicando que te falta el módulo `encodings` y en los pantallazos no se ve la variable `PYTHONPATH`, así que lo primero que debes comprobar es que está definida y que contiene las rutas de tu instalación de `Python` ...

Comment: efectivamente me sale que está en ejecución @fredyfx PostgreSQL Server 14 | Estado: En Ejecución | Tipo de Inicio: Automático

Comment: y eso que dices @FranciscoJavier como debería hacerlo... la verdad que para este punto ya no se tanto de eso

Comment: Creas en las variables de sistema una variable llamada `PYTHONPATH` y Le añades las mismas rutas que se ven en la variable de usuario `PATH`, además de otras rutas que puedas necesitar...

Comment: @FranciscoJavier ya lo hice, pero sigue igual, tal vez deba reiniciar? agregue todas las rutas de la versión 3.10 y 3.9